# batch prefix sequential numbers to file names

Tags: bash, numbers, rename, sequential

Trying to rename a set of files prefixed with sequential numbers. Would like to pad the single digits with a zero.

```
03_file_9YIl.pdf
05_file_ehQh.pdf
08_file_fxUy.pdf
09_file_fxUy.pdf
```

Problem:
The already two digit numbers also get padded.

```
04_file_9YIl.pdf
07_file_ehQh.pdf
08_file_fxUy.pdf
010_file_IEb1.pdf
014_file_kT9X.pdf
015_file_L6eG.pdf
020_file_t3QF.pdf
021_file_u00K.pdf
```

What I have tried:

```
n=0
for f in *
 do 
    if [ "$f" = "rename.sh" ]
        then
            continue
    fi
printf -v new "%$((++n))_$f"
echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"
done
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use utilise the regex flag of find to get the exact files required and so:

```
while read file
do
   fil=${file##*/}   # Extract the file name from the path
   dir=${file%/*}    # Extract the directory from the path
   echo "mv -f $line $dir/0$fil"
   # mv -f "$line" "$dir/0$fil" # Build the move command
done <<< "$(find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*/[[:digit:]]{1}_.*pdf$' -printf "%f\n")"
```

Uncomment the actual mv command once you have verified that the echo of the command look as exptected.